# XSLT Insert Nodes before the first node based on Value of Child

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML looks like this:

```xml
<Articles>
        <Article>
            <Position>Body</Position>
            <Categorie>Food</Categorie>
            <ProductName>Apple</ProductName>
        </Article>
        <Article>
            <Position>Body</Position>
            <Categorie>Food</Categorie>
            <ProductName>Pineapple</ProductName>
        </Article>
        <Article>
            <Position>Body</Position>
            <Categorie>Drinks</Categorie>
            <ProductName>Water</ProductName>
        </Article>
        <Article>
            <Position>Body</Position>
            <Categorie>Drinks</Categorie>
            <ProductName>CocaCola</ProductName>
        </Article>
</Articles>
```

after the Transformation it should look like this:

```xml
<Articles>
        <Article>
            <Position>Title</Position>
            <Titlename>Food</Titlename>
        </Article>
        <Article>
            <Position>Body</Position>
            <Categorie>Food</Categorie>
            <ProductName>Apple</ProductName>
        </Article>
        <Article>
            <Position>Body</Position>
            <Categorie>Food</Categorie>
            <ProductName>Pineapple</ProductName>
        </Article>
        <Article>
            <Position>Title</Position>
            <Titlename>Drinks</Titlename>
        </Article>
        <Article>
            <Position>Body</Position>
            <Categorie>Drinks</Categorie>
            <ProductName>Water</ProductName>
        </Article>
        <Article>
            <Position>Body</Position>
            <Categorie>Drinks</Categorie>
            <ProductName>CocaCola</ProductName>
        </Article>
</Articles>
```

The Number of Categories can be variable, so i need an XLST-Stylesheet which checks if the Value of `<Categorie>` Tag is the first one.

If it is, it should copy this part above the Article:

```xml
       `<Article>
        <Position>Title</Position>
        <Titlename>Food</Titlename>
        </Article>`
```

Here is my attempt:

Important to know i'm limited to v1.0

```
<xsl:for-each select="Article">
    <xsl:if test="Position/Categorie = First()">
        <Article>
            <Position><xsl:value-of Select ="Title"></Position>
            <Titlename><xsl:value-of Select ="Categorie"></Titlename>
        </Article>
    </xsl:if>


        <Article>
            <Position><xsl:value-of Select ="Position"></Position>
            <Categorie><xsl:value-of Select ="Categorie"></Categorie>
            <ProductName><xsl:value-of Select ="ProductName"></ProductName>
        </Article>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You say "*Insert Nodes after Last Node*", but you mean **before the first node** in the group, do you not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Articles">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Article">
            <xsl:if test="not(Categorie=preceding-sibling::Article/Categorie)">
                <Article>
                    <Position>Title</Position>
                    <Titlename>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Categorie"/>
                    </Titlename>
                </Article>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks michael that's exacly what i was looking for.